# Detailed Magento2 events reference

Tags: magento2

Where can I find a good and detailed description about Magento2 events? 
I would prefer a complete reference, but still not found.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is probably a question for Magento StackExchange – https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this covers your needs, but I am working with cyrillschumacher's list of dispatched events. [cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.3-list-of-all-dispatched-events](https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.3-list-of-all-dispatched-events/)